# OPA doesn't find key if its value is false

Tags: opa, open-policy-agent

I have noticed that if a certain key has `false` as a value, OPA ignores it. Take this policy code:

```
package play

violation[{"msg": msg}] {
    provided := {context | input.securityContext[context]}
    required := {context | context := input.requiredContexts[_]}
    missing := required - provided
    count(missing) > 0
    msg := sprintf("Missing: %v. Provided: %v. Required: %v", [missing, provided, required])
}
```

given the following input:

```
{
    "requiredContexts": [
        "runAsNonRoot",
        "privileged"
    ],
    "securityContext": {
        "capabilities": {
            "add": [
                "NET_ADMIN",
                "SYS_TIME"
            ]
        },
        "runAsNonRoot": true,
        "privileged": false
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
{
    "violation": [
        {
            "msg": "Missing: {\"privileged\"}. Provided: {\"capabilities\", \"runAsNonRoot\"}. Required: {\"privileged\", \"runAsNonRoot\"}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice how `privileged` is missing even though it is provided in the input.

If `privileged` is switched to `true`, the code behaves as expected. I think this is me not knowing OPA well enough. Why does this happen?

https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/TAcoRAZZcS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good observation! What you're seeing using that type of looping construct, i.e.

```
provided := {context | input.securityContext[context]}
```

Is the result of [unification](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#unification-), meaning that OPA "will assign variables to values that make the comparison true". The `false` value does not make the evaluation true. If you want to stick to the "old" (but certainly still valid) looping construct, you can make the unification explicit using a wildcard on the left hand side, basically saying that you don't care which value it's assigned.

```
provided := {context | _ = input.securityContext[context]}
```

If you think that's hard to grasp, you wouldn't be alone. Modern Rego instead often prefer to make use of the more recent `some ... in` construct for iteration, which is similar to `for k, v in ...`, where you also may make use of a wildcard if you don't care for either the key or the value:

```
import future.keywords.in

provided := {context | some context, _ in input.securityContext}
```

If you're only interested in the keys however, I'd recommend using the fairly recent `object.keys` built-in function:

```
provided := object.keys(input.securityContext)
```